# How to find contigs in a text file?

Tags: shell, grep

I need to find the contigs in a text file. I used the following command:

```
grep > filename
```

Yet it yielded only `>chr`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide what your file contains and your desired output to be able to understand what you want to achieve

Comment: What is a "contig"?

Comment: `>` is the redirection operator, so must be escaped when searching for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pipes to get the output from `cat`, although in this case it is useless, using direct `grep` would work for you:

```sh
grep config filename
```

Comment: Note that the question said "contig", not "config", and that `>` is the character used in fasta files (a format used for storing genomic sequence data, where `>` indicates a "header line"). They haven't given any information apart from a few hints (that are only useful to bioinformaticians) to what they want to do, so I have closed the question as unclear.